# INSERT QUERY Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have problem in my insert function. Function not running on insert line given below

```
public function InsertFormData($data,$Formid)
{
    $this->db->select('FormName');
    $this->db->where('Formid',$Formid);
    $q = $this->db->get('form');
    $data = $q->result_array();
    $FormName = $data[0]['FormName'];
    $this -> db ->insert($FormName, $data); this line not execute
    return $FormName;
}
```

Comment: You can't insert multi-dimensionnal array using db->insert; You should look to insert_batch.

Comment: Do not use database queries in controllers, that's why you're using MVC. Only model should use `$this->db`. Also, run `var_dump($data)`, just after defining it.

Answer (score 0):

Make two functions in your model.

```
public function getFormName($formId)
{
    $this->db->select('FormName');
    $this->db->where('Formid',$Formid);
    $q = $this->db->get('form');
    $data = $q->result();
    return $data;
}

public function InsertFormData($data,$Formid)
{
    $data = $this->getFormName($Formid);
    $formName = $data[0]->FormName;

    $this->db->insert($formName, $data);
    return $FormName;
}
```

Not tested, But I hope it'll help you.